# failed to omit Columns containing NA values with: na.rm=TRUE and na.action=NULL

Tags: r, aggregate-functions

I wanted to get the same output as the one on: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-aggregate-data-in-r/

My output is:

```
Group.1 Group.2 Name Role Shift Salary  Age
1    Cook  Dinner   NA   NA    NA   1800 25.0
2 Manager  Dinner   NA   NA    NA   2000 41.0
3  Server  Dinner   NA   NA    NA   1650 27.5
4    Cook   Lunch   NA   NA    NA   1200 24.0
5 Manager   Lunch   NA   NA    NA   2200 32.0
6  Server   Lunch   NA   NA    NA   1350 24.0
```

with Columns containing `NA`s. Including `"na.rm=TRUE"` and `"na.action=NULL"` did not make any difference.

I also keep receiving warnings:

> Warning messages:
>   1: In mean.default(X[[i]], ...) :
>    argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

How do I modify `aggregate()` which would make it omit unnecessary columns and\or `NA` values without having to resort to using `dplyr`?

Thanks

```
agg = aggregate(data,
                 by = list(data$Role, data$Shift),
                 FUN = mean, na.rm=TRUE, na.action=NULL)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at your `aggregate` call

```
aggregate(data, by = list(data$Role, data$Shift), FUN = mean)
```

Here you are calculating the average of values across *all* columns of `data` by `data$Role` and `data$Shift` (which are your grouping variables).

The error is pretty self-explanatory in telling you that you are trying to calculate the mean of non-numeric entries. `data$Name`, `data$Role` and `data$Shift` are all non-numeric columns.

I assume you are after

```
aggregate(. ~ Role + Shift, data = data[, -1], FUN = mean)
#     Role  Shift Salary  Age
#1    Cook Dinner   1800 25.0
#2 Manager Dinner   2000 41.0
#3  Server Dinner   1650 27.5
#4    Cook  Lunch   1200 24.0
#5 Manager  Lunch   2200 32.0
#6  Server  Lunch   1350 24.0
```

The `.` (dot) here denotes all variables *except* the ones on the RHS of the `~` (tilde). Notice how we *exclude* `data$Name` by passing `data[, -1]` as the `data` argument to `aggregate`.

Or using the `by` syntax

```
aggregate(data[, c("Salary", "Age")], by = list(data$Role, data$Shift), FUN = "mean")
```

Here the `x` argument refers to all columns the values of which you want to aggregate according to groups defined in `by`.

---

In response to your comment, to aggregate only by `Role`

```
aggregate(cbind(Salary, Age) ~ Role, data = data[, -1], FUN = mean)
#    Role Salary   Age
#1    Cook   1500 24.50
#2 Manager   2100 36.50
#3  Server   1500 25.75
```

Comment: @RonakShah Agreed, or perhaps `aggregate(cbind(Salary, Age)~Role + Shift,data, mean)`

Comment: I get the same output with '> data' as in that website. with: ```` > agg = aggregate(data,
                 by = list(data$Role),
                 FUN = mean)   
```` 
With the code above I should had received the same output, too, which would be without any Columns with NAs

Comment: @analytics-josh Yes, above analysis is based on that same data.

Comment: 1 Cook       1500.0 24.5
2 Manager 2100.0 36.5
3 Server    1500.0 25.8                This is the output i am after (refer to the link above)

Comment: @analytics-josh So you only want to aggregate by `data$Role`? Why do you then include `data$Shift` in your original attempt? Either way, I've made an edit to show you  how to aggregate `Salary` and `Age` by `Role`.

Comment: The original attempt was to aggregate by data$Role only w/t data$Shift. In both cases I have been getting this issue with NAs. Sorry, I should had specified that. I tried your solutions and neither of them produce as per the website's link. Thanks

Comment: @analytics-josh *"I tried your solutions and neither of them produce as per the website's link"* The last addition to my post reproduces **exactly** the results from the link (compare with the table before section "The aggregate function"). It would be *very* helpful if you were more specific both in your problem statement (people are proffering their free time to help you with *your* problem, we can only work with details you explicitly give) and with any downstream assessment.

Comment: @analytics-josh Lastly, the error you are seeing is really quite descriptive. It boils down to you not using `aggregate` correctly. Either use `aggregate` with the `formula` syntax or with the `x`/`by` syntax. In both cases, you need to specify the grouping variables/columns and the variables/columns holding the values you'd like to summarise/aggregate.

Comment: Copying and pasting website's solutions yields to warnings due to columns containing NAs. This leads me to believe that what they have on the web site is simply incorrect. I just started learning how aggregate() works and what seems obvious to more experienced people, may not be obvious to me. **aggregate(cbind(Salary, Age) ~ Role, data = data[, -1], FUN = mean)** is the solution. Did not refresh the page and kept trying with your orig. resp.However, it is hard for me to understand this syntax at this point and I was trying to make it work with a simpler syntax which was on the website. Thanks